Though able enough? Compatible?

He was trying to be compatible. Though able enough, he felt he was a lover more from duty than from inclination. With his wife he had not had to try. From her he had met with reprimands for inopportune fondling, for lingering about, ...

He was trying to be compatible with his current girlfriend and I have two questions.

Does this(the first bold sentence) mean "though he was able to be a lover" or "though he was gifted/potent enough"?
Does the second one ("with his wife he had not had to try") mean "he had not had to try be compatible with his wife because he had loved her and that love, that desire he had for her wife exempted him from trying to be compatible with her." ?


That's it, more or less. He found his wife very attractive, his current girlfriend not so much.

What does the title mean?

@MichaelHarvey  excuse me. I didn't notice. I wanted to write something else.

By the way: (1) Yes. (2) Yes.

From the contrast drawn with the new "her", one gathers that his wife and he were sexually compatible by nature, whereas with the new woman he must make an effort to discern her mood, at least if he doesn't want to meet with reprimands.But he doesn't really feel desire for the new woman in any case; he approaches her out of a sense of duty.

@TimR this " her" in this sentence "From her he had met with reprimands for inopportune fondling," refers to her wife.

@SoroushGh There's no way to know that from the excerpt you've quoted; nor does it make much sense.  Please quote a larger excerpt that shows the antecedent of "her".

The word able as cited is relatively old-fashioned / dated / literary / stilted compared to today's preferred capable enough.

@FumbleFingers he was capable enough to be a lover?

@TimR I added some sentences on another comment section in answer to Boner answer that maybe help to comprehend better this sentence.

Sure. It's just a bit affected / literary. But we might more naturally phrase it as Although he was quite capable of being a [good] lover, he did so out of a sense of duty rather than personal desire.

This is "able" without being followed by "to [verb]." The Merriam-Webster entry that matches this best is

2: marked by intelligence, knowledge, skill, or competence ("an able administrator")

In other words, being "good at" something, or at least "good enough." Usually that "something" is implied by context: an "able runner" is pretty good at running. But the meaning is a bit different than "able to run," which simply means that running is not impossible for the person.
There isn't enough context in this quote to say whether your reading in your second question is fully correct (it's not totally clear to me whether he felt strong love toward his wife), but it's likely that by using "try" when the author had just used it two sentences ago, yes, it means "try [to be compatible]."

thank you so much. A question about the first one occured to me. So what is he good at? Good at being compatible ?

.., trying to embrace her over the sink or on her way between stove and refrigerator, for entering the bathroom to ask if he could join her in the tub. At times his wife had been coyly elusive, insinuating rewards for deferment, at times cross, shouting that he interfered with her housework and allowed her no peace. Then he had been hurt and sulked on the sofa, silently cursing her and grinding his
teeth. Eventually he had gone to her with apologies and contrite embraces
that again brought on a burgeoning of desire.That desire, that yearning for
her, had been the foundation of his marriage

@SoroushGh "An able lover" = "pretty good, or good enough, at being a lover." Meanwhile you can edit the question to add the extra context; comments aren't an official part of the question. It sounds like your reading is pretty accurate.
